# How to prevent Brakeman 'unprotected redirect' warning when redirect to external domain is desired?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, brakeman

A model in a Rails app has a url column, where users can enter the address of external sites.

The urls are displayed on a page. When clicked, in addition to routing to that url, I need to perform some actions in the app. So I defined a controller action as follows

```
#objects_controller.rb

def click
  @object = Object.find params[:id]
  # do some stuff
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @object.url }
  end
end
```

and in the view

```
<%= 'click me', click_object_path @object %>
```

Brakeman is (as expected) throwing a warning

```
High - Redirect - Possible unprotected redirect
```

Normally the solution to this would be to add `only_path: true` to the redirect and only allow redirects within the current app. But in this case the desired behaviour is to navigate to an external site.

My questions

1. Are there any steps I should be taking to ensure malicious code cannot be entered and activated from the Object.url column (or in other words, is my click controller action the best way to archive the desired in-app actions plus navigation)?
2. If this is the correct approach, is there a way to quieten Brakeman so that this particular issue is no longer reported?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For anyone else having a similar issue, I added some checks to my controller to verify that @object.url is indeed a properly formatted url.

```
def click
  @object = Object.find params[:id]
  if @object.url =~ URI::regexp
    obj_url = URI.parse(@object.url)
  else
    obj_url = nil
  end
  # do some stuff
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to obj_url }
  end
end
```

And Brakeman reports `1 fixed warning`. Result!

Comment: Hey, @Andy. I am facing the same problem but when I use this solution, I am getting NoMethodError (undefined method `to_model' for #<URI::HTTPS https://google.com>). What could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: @AnkitSamarthya what does `@object.url` return in your example?

Comment: And the line returning the error is `obj_url = URI.parse(@object.url)`?

Comment: `to_model` errors are usually the result of `@object` not being a single AR object. For example if 'Object.where' is used in place of `Object.find`

Comment: Hey, line returning the error is redirect_to obj_url.

Comment: just do 'redirect_to obj_url.to_s'